# Evaluating K means clustering using python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a data set slightly similar like this:

[image]

I have performed **K means clustering** using this code:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq
data=np.matrix(dataAll.ix[:,:-1])
centers, _ = kmeans(data, 3, iter=100)
cluster, _ = vq(data, centers)
```

In here I want to ask how to evaluate **k means clustering**. I want to get value such as precision, accuracy, **f measure**.

Comment: Those tests only work if you know what the correct cluster labels are supposed to be (i.e. you know which cluster each data point belongs to). Typically, that's not how you evaluate clustering, which is generally associated with unsupervised learning. You might therefore consider looking into intra-cluster variances, and inter-cluster distances

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570610/k-means-in-python-determine-which-data-are-associated-with-each-centroid), the k means can return the label, so I think we can get precision, accuracy, and f measure because we have known the label for each data. I just though like that, may be I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, k-means returns class labels. However, you can't measure precision/accuracy without knowing the correct labels, to check whether k-means got it right. This is what I said in my previous comment

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i am coding my own application and i know the class labels. So how can i evaluate ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: depends on what kind of evaluation you're interested in. OP mentions precision, accuracy and f measure, which are all valid

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i am interested in f measure can you check this question ty very much : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404742/how-to-calculate-clustering-success-pre-assigment-true-classes-are-known

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Gold standard/Ground truth values, you can use my code [**[Link](https://sutanto.org/pairwise-fscore-nmi/)**] to calculate pairwise precision, recall, FScore & NMI.

Notes, that the article is in Indonesian language, but don't worry you can skip all of the explanations and go straight to the code at the bottom of the article. [I wrote Matlab & Python implementation]
The python code is a fork of **[this work](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/60711/)** that is available **[here](http://greententacle.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/reseed/reseed_eval.py)**.