# Getting cluster contents, scipy k-means

Tags: python, scipy, k-means

I have a dataset consisting of on-screen co-ordinates (x, y). I am running k-means from sci-py and obtaining clusters, but I'd like to inspect the contents of each cluster. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: http://blog.mpacula.com/2011/04/27/k-means-clustering-example-python/  provides a code example of plotting scipy kmeans clustering results

Comment: This plots stuff. I can already do that. I wanted to list the contents of each cluster. For example, say I set k = 10, is there is way for each cluster to print the input vectors that are "contained" (or close to) the centroid for the cluster?

Comment: See  the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570610/k-means-in-python-determine-which-data-are-associated-with-each-centroid

Comment: yeah...I went and reread the documentation and figured vector quantization and codebooks are what I needed. thanks. Can you post your link as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks but I just gave a reference and am not seeking points. I always post a comment if its short enough to fit (seems that 600 chars is the max comment size).